# Cloud firestore get all documents between two ids of documents

Tags: java, google-cloud-firestore, epoch

I have a collection with all document ids as epochtime(1613728796). Each of these documents contains up to 50 fields in it. I wanted to query set of documents between specific timing. How I can query based on document's uid?

```
Query query = db.collection("my-collection").whereGreaterThan("uid", "1613728796")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Query query = db.collection("my-collection").whereGreaterThan("__name__", "1613728796").whereLessThan("__name__", "1613728796")
```

Replace the above epoch times with the correct ones.

If that doesn't work, try replacing `"__name"` with `FieldPath.documentId()` or `FieldPath.documentId`

Comment: yes...FieldPath.documentId() works on 7.1.0 version, thanks.